# Capturing type parameter in anonymous class

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I would like to dynamically create a class which implements a given given interface and binds a type parameter of that interface. That's my interface definition:

```
public interface Container<T> {}
```

My initial thought was to use an anonymous class for this, like so:

```
public <T> Class<?> getContainerImplementationForType(Class<T> type) {
    return new Container<T> { ... }.getClass();
}
```

But if I examine the returned class object, the type parameter `T` of this implementation is not bound to whatever has been passed as `type` but it's still just a type variable `T`.

I got a vague idea why this is not working but am wondering how to achieve my goal. Is creating the type manually using ASM, ByteBuddy or similar to only way to go? I reckon dynamic proxies also won't work as I couldn't find a way to specify type parameter bounds for `Container` when obtaining a proxy class.

Comment: How is the class header look like in which getContainerImplementationForType() method is present?

Comment: It's a plain simple class, no type parameters etc. `getContainerImplementationForType()` could also be a static method for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

As the javadoc states, [getGenericInterfaces()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces--) only returns **static** type values from the source code:

> If a superinterface is a parameterized type, the Type object returned for it must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the **source code**.

...while in your source code it's **dynamic** `T`.

To put it another way: in Java, generic type information is not stored in RAM as a part of object instances and what reflection really does is mostly just providing static info from bytecode (like from `*.class` files). Thus, to be able to obtain the value of a type argument passed to a super class / implemented interface, this info must be hardcoded in the bytecode of **each** subclass/implementer on which you will call `getGenericInterfaces()` / `getGenericSuperclass()`. OTOH, in your source code there's only just **one** implementer, who is **generic**, so you will have just 1 class-file without any static type info (because it's generic). As explained, when a `Container` instance is created it will not hold any reference to the class that was used as `T` argument (you can only create a custom field/method in your anonymous class referencing `type` argument of `getContainerImplementationForType(type)`).

If you must use reflection to obtain the type value, then the only solution is exactly as you pointed: to dynamically create each time `getContainerImplementationForType(type)` is called, a bytecode (dynamic ByteBuddy/ASM class) that will store the given type value.
As mentioned, an alternative to reflection may be to add to your anonymous class (and to `Container` interface if it's under your control) a method like `getContainerType()`, that will return `type` argument of `getContainerImplementationForType(type)`.